# onClickListener is not getting fired

Tags: android

Im trying to fire onClick Event from a custom view but onClickListener is not getting fired

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myorders_fragment, container, false);
    linear = (LinearLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.linear);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.segment_text);
    pending = (RadioButton) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.button_one);
    completed = (RadioButton) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.button_two);

    //  radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            if (group == radioGroup) {
                if (checkedId == R.id.button_one) {

                    for (int i =0 ;i<=3;i++) {
                        mChildView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pending_orders_fragment, linear);

                       mChildView.setClickable(true);
                        mChildView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"sdf",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });


                    }

                } else if (checkedId == R.id.button_two) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"completed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 //   mChildView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pending_orders_fragment, linear);

                }
            }
        }
    });
    return mRootView;
}
```

child view has to be clickable and it should fire onClickListener. Why is that onClickListener is not getting fired? or should I try implementing onTouchListener?

Comment: are you sure, the `onCheckedChanged()` is getting invoked?

Comment: yes! onCheckedChanged is working onClickListener for a custom view is not getting invoked

Comment: are you sure the code is passing all those if conditions?

Comment: yes.The code inflates the child view thrice on the screen but it never adds onClickListener to those child views

Comment: Did you try the ontouch listener?

Comment: not yet..i have not tried onTouchListener

Comment: Ok will show you a example tell me if works pls

Answer (score 2):

Your childViews do not have a parent, that's why `OnClick` is not callend. You are only inflating them, but not adding them to a parent. You should call `addView` on the `LinearLayout` with the children if they are not there. Otherwise, call `getChildAt` on the `LinearLayout` instead of inflating them if you already have them in the `LinearLayout`

Comment: ` java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first` is getting thrown as an error message

Comment: That means that your children already have a parent and you should get the children using the getChidlAt call instead of inflating them

Comment: ok then let me try using `linear.getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener` method

Comment: still onClickListener  is not getting fired

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if works please:

```
mChildView
.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
      public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
           if (hasFocus) {
                v.performClick();
             }
         }
  });
```

Comment: still it is not getting fired

Comment: should I call setOnClickListener along with setFoucusChangeListener?